# Struct member names as map keys

Tags: c++

I'm looking for a way to map a struct's member to a string (or some other type for that matter):

```
struct Foo
{
    int intMember;
    int otherIntMember;
    char charMember;
    std::optional<int> optIntMember;
};

std::map<???, std::string> myMap = {
    {Foo::intMember, "IntMemberName"},
    {Foo::otherIntMember, "OtherIntMemberName"},
    {Foo::charMember, "CharMemberName"},
    {Foo::optIntMember, "OptIntMemberName"}
};

void myFunc()
{
    std::cout << myMap[Foo::intMember] << std::endl;
    std::cout << myMap[Foo::otherintMember] << std::endl;
    std::cout << myMap[Foo::charMember] << std::endl;
    std::cout << myMap[Foo::optIntMember] << std::endl;
}
```

One possible approach I've seen so far is using `offsetof` to map offsets to strings (which looks like a way outdated and bug-prone function). Having an enum for each of the members might also be an option but that honestly feels bulky and like an overkill.

Is there a simple elegant way to achieve this in modern C++?

Comment: You can put those members into a tuple. Then, each will have a unique index and mapping of these indexes to strings is trivial. However, this overall seems to be an [_XY problem_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/455871).

Comment: It looks like you are looking for reflection. C++ doesn't have this feature yet. Likely it will in a future version.

Comment: why do you want to map members like that?

Comment: @DanielLangr I see, `std::pair` might have worked in this case. I discarded it initially because this struct is already being initialized and passed around in some existing code and changing the struct itself would call for a cascade of changes. Take this as more of a conceptual question than actually trying to find a solution to a real problem.

Comment: @JHBonarius quick googling tells me this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the keyword.

Comment: @phuclv in my case, I'm working on an xml serializer and I wanted the members' corresponding xml tags to be bundled together nicely instead of being hardcoded here and there. But it was more curiosity than a need for a concrete solution. I see from comments that "reflection" is what I was looking for.

Comment: reflection is not very good for performance. You should use an xml library instead

Comment: @phuclv I already do :) This piece of code is before the serialization. Is your performance concern theoretical or from trying out (or reading about) the experimental implementation?